# VSTO 2012 PowerPoint Add-in with macros

Tags: vb.net, macros, powerpoint, add-in, ribbon

i'm trying to make an add-in ribbon for powerpoint with a button than can add a slide with 2 command buttons  that has text box each.

Please I really need help. This is my thesis and I want to graduate. you don't have to give codes. just want tutorials or something I can learn from.

Its kind of like with Microsoft Mouse Mischief but with a database for the scores.

Answer (score 0):

VBA macros and COM add-ins are different things. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for PowerPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668192.aspx).

VSTO allows to customize the Ribbon UI in the following ways:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)

Comment: So.. which would you suggest I use? VBA macros or COM add-ins?

Comment: VBA macros are not designed for distributing on multiple PCs. So, if you need the code running only on your machine, you can develop a macro. But if you want to set up the solution on other machines you need to develop an add-in.

Comment: I creating an add-in that can be installed like Microsoft Mouse Mischief. Then I don't need to use macros? Then how can I put command buttons?

Comment: I've found this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19175f33-d007-499b-8041-7c8881c4884f/powerpoint-slide-and-c?forum=innovateonoffice    I think we have the same problem. one answer said that he should use macros..

Comment: Eugene:  "VBA macros are not designed for distributing ..."?  It's true that you need to create an add-in for this, yes, but you can create add-ins using VBA.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I have already created a ribbon using the PowerPoint 2010 Add-in in VSTO 2012. I had also created a button than can create a new slide but I'm really having a hard time creating a button in the ribbon that can create a slide with command buttons. PLEASE I really need help. Am I gonna have to use Macros? or something else? Really appreciate the Help.

Comment: I don't use VSTO, so can't help with the specifics, but could probably help with the object model manipulation in general terms if you post the code you already have and explain what you mean by "that has text box" in your original question.